# How to store a turn based game state in Node.js

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am developing a turn based mobile game which is a question - answer game. Basicly server will send a question to players (there will be two players in a match) then player 1 answers this question after that, player 2 will be answering too the same question in a limited time order. Players could use jokers such as extend the time or change the question. This is the basic logic of my game. So here is my question:

I will be using Node.js and Socket.io for the server side. You know whether a player losts the connection to the server or simply kills the app starts again during in a match, they should be rejoin the same match and they should see what happened in the game when they were not there. How should i store the game state in my server?

**My approach:**

There will be a Game class that stores every state of the game and manages the countdowns for turns with setInterval method etc. and when the match starts i will create them and store like this:

```
activeGames[lobbyId] = new Game(player1, player2, lobbyId)
```

So for example if a player uses a joker i will catch that request inside the socket.io then retrive my class like this:

```
var yourGame = activeGames[lobbyId]

yourGame.useBonus(player1, bonusType)
```

So all the status of the game will be stored inside the class. But with this approach if my server dies or restarts etc. all active matches will be dropped. So that is not a good thing. What do you suggest about this problem? How my server should store the active matches?

*Ps: Matches will be lasted for 3 minutes. After that i don't need the match history or something like that. So i am not looking for a persistent database solution.*

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you would generate a token (preferrably a cryptographically-secure one) for each client. When a client joins for the first time, generate the game data, and associate that data with the token. Then, send that token to the client. When the client reconnects, it can send that token back to the server, which then re-associates the data with the client.

As for server issues, there are many ways to go about things. What I'd do is create a folder called `temp` or `session` or something, then store each game in its own temp file. When the server restarts, it checks the temp folder for game files, loads them, then clears their temp files. You can add handlers for `unhandledException` and `unhandledRejection` in NodeJS to save currently active games to their own temp files before the server crashes or shuts down.